# ffmpeg Unrecognized option...Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, wmv

This is probably a pretty simple question for those of you who use ffmpeg, but I'm very new at it, and I'm using it on Windows, which apparently isn't the norm.

From cmd, with my environment variable set at my ffmpeg install directory, I'm running

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Me\Videos\InputVideo.wmv
-vcodec libx264 -acodec aacenc C:\Users\Me\Desktop\OutputVideo.mp4
```

(My actual script doesn't have a line break, I just put that there to make reading easier)

and ffmpeg is throwing

```
Unrecognized option 'i C:\Users\Me\Videos\InputVideo.wmv
-vcodec libx264 -acodec aacenc C:\Users\Me\Desktop\OutputVideo.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found.
```

Is something wrong with my script?  Am I calling an encoder that isn't currently on my machine?  Is it something to do with the file paths?

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: There is no encoder named `aacenc`. See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for possible choices (depending on your ffmpeg configuration).

Comment: I just realized this.  I forgot the libvo_!

Comment: I recommend the native AAC encoder `-codec:a aac -strict experimental` over `libvo_aacenc`. See the link I provided for more info.

Comment: I actually sort of solved this problem on my own a few hours ago.  I'm using libfdk_aac because that guide says it's the best one.

Comment: **String[] cmd = new String[4];
            cmd[0] = "ffmpeg ";
            cmd[1] = " -i ";
            cmd[2] = recordedFileName+"  ";
            cmd[3] = "  "+sampleDir+"/"+"sampleAudio.wav";** this is how I have written my command, Is it correct??? If not, please correct me..